# .NET CORE 3.1 Deployment using Azure Pipeline -> Error Could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms in OpenXmlPowerTools

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, build, azure-pipelines

I am using .NET Core Web API Application which contains reference to the OpenXmlPowerTools package. I am getting below error message if I am deploying my code thorough Azure Pipeline on server. Same thing is working properly if I am deploying it manually (i.e. Publishing Code on my Local machine and Deploying it on Server)

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at OpenXmlPowerTools.WordprocessingMLUtil.CalcWidthOfRunInTwips(XElement r)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.FormattingAssembler.NormalizeListItemsTransform(FormattingAssemblerInfo fai, WordprocessingDocument wDoc, XNode node, FormattingAssemblerSettings settings)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.FormattingAssembler.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<NormalizeListItemsTransform>b__6(XNode n)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement..ctor(XName name, Object[] content)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.FormattingAssembler.NormalizeListItemsTransform(FormattingAssemblerInfo fai, WordprocessingDocument wDoc, XNode node, FormattingAssemblerSettings settings)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.FormattingAssembler.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<NormalizeListItemsTransform>b__6(XNode n)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement..ctor(XName name, Object[] content)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.FormattingAssembler.NormalizeListItemsTransform(FormattingAssemblerInfo fai, WordprocessingDocument wDoc, XNode node, FormattingAssemblerSettings settings)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.FormattingAssembler.NormalizeListItems(FormattingAssemblerInfo fai, WordprocessingDocument wDoc, FormattingAssemblerSettings settings)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.FormattingAssembler.AssembleFormatting(WordprocessingDocument wDoc, FormattingAssemblerSettings settings)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.WmlToHtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, WmlToHtmlConverterSettings htmlConverterSettings)
   at OpenXmlPowerTools.HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(WordprocessingDocument wDoc, HtmlConverterSettings htmlConverterSettings)
   at myC.IA.Helper.Helper.DocHelper.GenerateHTMLFromWordOrXML(String docfilepath, FileInfo fi, WordprocessingDocument wDoc, FileInfo destFileName, Int32 requestId, String artifactName, String artifactType, String type)
```

Not sure exactly what is the issue. If anything additional is needed then I can update the answer accordingly.

Tasks present in CI pipeline
[image]

Tasks present in CD pipeline
[image]

There is diff in the runtimeconfig file generated by Pipeline and Local Publish.

**runtimeconfig file generated by pipeline**

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
      "version": "3.1.0"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

**runtimeconfig file generated by local publish**

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",
        "version": "3.1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "3.1.0"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}
```

If I am replacing the file generated on local with file generated by pipeline then it is working properly. Do I need to do any changes in the pipeline to generate same file as local?

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: @jessehouwing Added screenshots of the same.

Comment: Could you please share .csproj file packages references.